# Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93) now-ui-kit

Tags: reactjs, node-sass

> ./src/assets/scss/now-ui-kit.scss?v=1.4.0 (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/assets/scss/now-ui-kit.scss?v=1.4.0)
> Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)
> For more information on which environments are supported please see:
> https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1

this is my old project, then when i run again now, it's always getting error. could anyone help me with this error please?

package.json file

```js
{
  "name": "now-ui-kit-react",
  "version": "1.4.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^25.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^3.0.1",
    "axios-react": "^2.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "gulp-append-prepend": "1.0.8",
    "lord-icon-element": "^2.0.2",
    "lottie-web": "^5.7.7",
    "moment": "2.26.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "nouislider": "14.5.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-alert": "^7.0.2",
    "react-alert-template-basic": "^1.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
    "react-bootstrap-switch": "15.5.3",
    "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^4.0.3",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator": "^2.1.2",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit": "^2.1.3",
    "react-content-loader": "^6.0.1",
    "react-datetime": "2.16.3",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.15.4",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-notifications": "^1.7.2",
    "react-router": "5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-validation": "^3.0.7",
    "reactstrap": "8.4.1",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "build": "react-scripts build && gulp licenses",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start",
    "compile-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/now-ui-kit.scss src/assets/css/now-ui-kit.css",
    "minify-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/now-ui-kit.scss src/assets/css/now-ui-kit.min.css --output-style compressed",
    "map-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/now-ui-kit.scss src/assets/css/now-ui-kit.css --source-map true"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "typescript": "3.9.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your node version and make sure you installed node x64 version.

Comment: See workaround mentioned on ["Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (108)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74979606/node-sass-does-not-yet-support-your-current-environment-windows-64-bit-with-un/75234435#75234435)