# "Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (108)"

Tags: node.js, npm, node-sass

I am trying to run Experience builder on windows 11 64 bit.
My Node version is V18.12.1 and npm version is V8.19.2 (Both the version are LTS version)

Whenever I am trying to run "npm start" command (in cmd) from the client folder of experience builder, I am getting this error  "Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (108)"

If anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

This error message does not indicate an problem with `Ionic`, but rather with `node-sass`, which is specified to execute in your `Gulp` file. The `node-sass` error, `Node Sass` does not yet support your current environment indicates that the version of `node-sass` you are trying to run is not compatible with the version of node installed.

Check the [Node Sass release notes](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/) for the version of `node-sass` you have, to see which version of node is required. If the version of node is wrong, you must downgrade node, or upgrade `node-sass`, until you have a compatible pair. If the node version is supported, you may just need to run `npm rebuild node-sass` (with -g if node-sass was installed globally). If that doesn't work, you can `npm uninstall node-sass && npm install node-sass` (again, with -g if necessary).